# Integrate Third Restful.json to get and post information into WordPress

Tags: php, rest, get, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using **Wordpress** and I want to integrate **fidel API** into my wordpress site. Where *(in which file)* to write the code for integration and also the code to integrate **fidel API** ?
I need to create a *earned cashback section* pulling the balance of what was spent, transaction location, and transaction history from the API.

Comment: Is this your real API key?

Comment: This is my test API Key Not my live Dharman